# Average/Count of a varying number of observations until a condition is met

Tags: sas

I have got a data set with the following structure:

```
ID  Date&Time   var1    var2
1   1/11        1       yes
1   3/11        3       no
1   3/11        2       no
1   5/11        5       yes
1   10/11       2       no
2   3/11        0       yes
2   12/11       1       no
2   23/11       2       yes
2   24/11       0       yes
3   5/11        1       yes
3   6/11        2       no
3   8/11        5       yes
3   9/11        4       no
```

It is a log-file with observations on which my analysis is based on. Now I would like to get a moving average considering, e.g. all observaitons of the last week (and month, year, etc.), i.e. I want a structure like the following:

```
ID  Date&Time   var1    var2    week_avg    week_count
1   1/11        1       yes     .           .
1   3/11        3       no      1           1
1   3/11        2       no      2           1
1   5/11        5       yes     2           1
1   10/11       2       no      3.33        1
2   3/11        0       yes     .           .
2   12/11       1       no      .           .
2   23/11       2       yes     .           .
2   24/11       0       yes     2           1
3   5/11        1       yes     .           .
3   6/11        2       no      1           1
3   8/11        5       yes     1.5         1
3   9/11        4       no      2.66        2
```

Is there a way to use the `lag`-function in something like a `do-until` loop?
Or is `PROC EXPAND` capable of performing a moving average by specifying a time window instead of a number of observations?

Comment: Can you clarify a little what you are doing? Are you saying that you would like a moving average for observations within a week using the data that you have? If so, you will first need to accumulate your data to a time-series within the interval that you are interested in. This can be achieved with a data step and `proc timeseries`

Comment: Do you have SAS-ETS licensed by any chance?

Comment: `proc timeseries` would work for just one transformation, right? Either in weeks or in months, for example?

Comment: I do have Enterprise Guide and Enterprise Miner available. Actually, I was not even aware of a specific time series SAS tool

Comment: SAS/ETS is separately licensed set of procedures for SAS.  Like SAS/Stat is separate from Base SAS.  Run `proc setinit;run;` to see what you have licensed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I actually do have access to SAS/ETS

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via by-processing, first creating the corresponding period values :

```
proc sort data=have ; by id date ; run ;

data periods ;
  set have ;
  year  = put(date,year4.) ;
  month = put(date,yymmn6.) ;
  week  = put(date,weeku5.) ;
run ;

data groups ;
  set periods ;
  retain week_tot week_cnt month_tot month_cnt year_tot year_cnt 0 ;
  /* For the first value in each period, set count & total values to . */
  if first.year then call missing(of year_:) ;
  if first.month then call missing(of month_:) ;
  if first.week then call missing(of week_:) ;

  /* Increment count by 1, total by var1, calculate average */
  /* Add any conditional logic on which to increment the running values */
  week_cnt  + 1 ; week_tot  + var1 ; week_avg  = week_tot  / week_cnt ;
  month_cnt + 1 ; month_tot + var1 ; month_avg = month_tot / month_cnt ;
  year_cnt  + 1 ; year_tot  + var1 ; year_avg  = year_tot  / year_cnt ;
run ;
```

You can then abstract the above into a macro if you so wish

```
%MACRO PERIOD_CALC(PD) ;
  retain &PD._cnt &PD._tot ;
  if first.&PD then call missing(of &PD._:) ;
  &PD._cnt + 1 ;
  &PD._tot + var1 ;
  &PD._avg = &PD._tot / &PD._cnt ;
%MEND ;

data groups ;
  set periods ;
  %PERIOD_CALC(week) ;
  %PERIOD_CALC(month) ;
  %PERIOD_CALC(year) ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and I am sorry for my late reply. It did not work exactly as I wanted to and I build a - cumbersome - solution myself.
The two issues I have with your propose:
- call missing() is not working. All values are the same for week, month, or year.
- And, most important: yoiur solution does treat every, e.g. week in a distinct manner. However, I do not want to start at 0 at the beginning of each week but just consider the last 7 days before the current date, regardless to which week they belong